# Putting extraRoutes in separate file for multiple configuration in Scully results in importerror

Tags: angular, scully, scullyio, angular-scully

I have multiple scully configurations:

```
scully.en.config.ts
scully.de.config.ts
```

The scully config has a extraRoutes fields which is same for all the configs. I want to put the extraRoutes in a new file `extraRoutes.ts`.

```
export const extraRoutes = [
   '/',
   '/about', etc...
]
```

And importing that file in configs

```
import { extraRoutes } from './extraRoutes';
```

But I am getting `Error: Cannot find module './extraRoutes'` while I try to run `npx scully --project en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file is automatically compiled during the Scully run.
However, it does not know about your extra file.
There are a couple of options.

1. compile it manually before run
2. Move it into the ./scully folder, and check the `tsconfig.json` there to see if its included (normally it is!)
3. just rename the file to `.js`,